# Android Fragment based on a 'Fragment Base'

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was wondering, is it possible to create a `BaseFragment` class which will inherit from `Fragment` and have some base UI (like 'Next fragment' and 'Previous fragment' buttons on bottom etc.) and then inherit from this `BaseFragment` to create `TargetFragment` which will add some custom UI to this from `BaseFragment`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. For your BaseFragment, you would need a layout file such as

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ViewStub/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your TargetFragment, populate the ViewStub with the layout you desire. Your 'Previous' and 'Next' button should handle the adding/removing of fragments.

Perhaps you could replace the ViewStub with a ViewPager; and add the fragments to the view pager adapter.